# Flutter how to align a list view builder to a datable inside a scroll view?

Tags: flutter, dart, uiscrollview, alignment

I have a list view builder of checkboxes and a data table. I want to have the checkboxes always aligned with the table.

When I add a new row to my table, the checkboxes become unaligned with the data table which will be confusing for the user if the corresponding checkbox is not aligned with its row.

Moreover, the scroll of the widgets must be linked. When I scroll my data table I want my list view of checkboxes to be scrolled with my data table.

Please let me know if you have any questions and I will try to clarify any doubts.

Sample image:
[image: How the program looks when running]

This is my sample code:

`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const ContactsSearchPage(),
    );
  }
}

class Contact {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String emailAddress;
  bool selected;

  Contact({
    this.firstName = '',
    this.lastName = '',
    this.emailAddress = '',
    this.selected = false,
  });
}

class ContactsSearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContactsSearchPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _ContactsSearchPageState createState() => _ContactsSearchPageState();
}

class _ContactsSearchPageState extends State<ContactsSearchPage> {
//List to hold selected contacts
  List<Contact> selectedContacts = [];
  bool allContactsSelected = false;

  //Initialize data table data
  List<DataRow> contactRows = [];
  List<Contact> rowsData = [];
  List<DataColumn> contactColumns = [];
  List<String> columnsData = [
    "First Name",
    "Last Name",
    "Email Address",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Fill the list of Columns
    contactColumns =
        buildListOfDataColumns(columnsData, Colors.white, TextAlign.center);

    //Fill the list of Contacts from object
    if (rowsData.isEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        rowsData.add(Contact(
          firstName: "user$i",
          lastName: "test$i",
          emailAddress: "email@test$i",
        ));
      }

      contactRows =
          buildContactListOfDataRows(rowsData, Colors.white, TextAlign.center);
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Data Table Test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Selected Contacts: ${selectedContacts.length}",
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      //Checkboxes
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 0, top: 130, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                        height: 400,
                        width: 100,
                        child: ScrollConfiguration(
                          behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context)
                              .copyWith(scrollbars: false),
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: rowsData.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return CheckboxListTile(
                                  value: rowsData[index].selected,
                                  onChanged: (selected) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      rowsData[index].selected =
                                          selected != null && selected != false
                                              ? true
                                              : false;

                                      if (rowsData[index].selected) {
                                        selectedContacts.add(rowsData[index]);
                                      } else {
                                        selectedContacts
                                            .remove(rowsData[index]);
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                );
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                      //Data Table to Hold all the Data
                      Container(
                        // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
                          maxHeight: 400,
                        ),
                        child: DataTable(
                            // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                            headingTextStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            ),
                            // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                            ),
                            border: TableBorder.all(
                              width: 1.5,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius:
                                  const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                            ),
                            columns: contactColumns,
                            rows: contactRows),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<DataRow> buildContactListOfDataRows(
      List<Contact> rowsData, Color textColor, TextAlign textAlign) {
    List<DataRow> dataRows = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsData.length; i++) {
      String firstName = rowsData[i].firstName;
      String lastName = rowsData[i].lastName;
      String emailAddress = rowsData[i].emailAddress;

      DataRow row = DataRow(
        cells: [
          DataCell(Text(
            firstName,
            style: TextStyle(color: textColor),
            textAlign: textAlign,
          )),
          DataCell(Text(
            lastName,
            style: TextStyle(color: textColor),
            textAlign: textAlign,
          )),
          DataCell(Text(
            emailAddress,
            style: TextStyle(color: textColor),
            textAlign: textAlign,
          )),
        ],
      );

      dataRows.add(row);
    }

    return dataRows;
  }

  List<DataColumn> buildListOfDataColumns(
      List<String> columnData, Color textColor, TextAlign textAlign) {
    List<DataColumn> dataColumns = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < columnData.length; i++) {
      String columnName = columnData[i];
      DataColumn column = const DataColumn(label: Text(""));

      column = DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          columnName,
          style: TextStyle(color: textColor),
          textAlign: textAlign,
        ),
      );

      dataColumns.add(column);
    }

    return dataColumns;
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) you can create a `DataTable` with the `showCheckboxColumn: true` option to make a row selectable.

Inside the `DataRow` options, add the `selected` option which takes a `bool` value, to decide whether the row is selected or not. Add another option `onSelectChanged` to the `DataRow` to perform a function when the row is selected.

Docs for [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) and [DataRow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataRow-class.html)